# Docker for windows: can't delete directory after it's been mounted to a container

Tags: windows, docker

I can't delete a directory after it's been mounted to a container.

I'm using image `node:lts-alpine`

When I run my container using

```
docker run --rm -v <<path_to_my_directory>>:/var/task:ro,delegated node:lts-alpine node <<path_to_my_node_script.js>>
```

(and it successfully finishes), the directory remains in a strange state, where I can't delete it.

I'm getting `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat`

I tried everything, deleting from the command line and from the windows file explorer.

`docker ps` doesn't show any running containers.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I somehow unmount it, or change permissions?

---

Windows: Windows 10 Education N, Version 1803

Docker desktop: 2.3.0.2 (45183)

Comment: That's kind of an unusual way to use Docker; if you're just trying to run a server-side Javascript script, installing Node is almost certainly simpler than installing Docker, getting the required administrator permissions to run it, and wrangling with filesystem sharing like this.  Iif you do need to run this in Docker, the standard way to run code in a container is to use a Dockerfile to create an image out of it; Docker has a [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial that walks through that process.

Comment: I had that before. Shut down the docker daemon and try to delete the folder from File Explorer. In last resort, restart your Windows, that should give you back the right on the folder.

Comment: That's not really an unusual way to use Docker at all. It's very common to run scripts in containers via volume mounts during development.

Comment: It's not unusual at all. The problem is, I can't restart docker daemon everytime my mounted volume changes. That's just not an option - it takes 20-30 seconds.